# ROSWTF ERRORS, ALL OF A SUDDEN?

Tags: turtlebot, rosnode, ros-electric, rostopic, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/roswtf/src/roswtf/__init__.py", line 208, in _roswtf_main
    wtf_check_graph(ctx, names=names)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/roswtf/src/roswtf/graph.py", line 413, in wtf_check_graph
    error_rule(r, r[0](ctx), ctx)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/roswtf/src/roswtf/graph.py", line 101, in ping_check
    _, unpinged = rosnode.rosnode_ping_all()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosnode/src/rosnode.py", line 335, in rosnode_ping_all
    if rosnode_ping(node, max_count=1, verbose=verbose):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosnode/src/rosnode.py", line 280, in rosnode_ping
    pid = _succeed(node.getPid(ID))
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosnode/src/rosnode.py", line 76, in _succeed
    raise ROSNodeException("remote call failed: %s"%msg)
ROSNodeException: remote call failed: not authorized
remote call failed: not authorized

Aborting checks, partial results summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /rviz_1337161842349946625:
   * /particlecloud
 * /rviz_1337161845242440654:
   * /particlecloud
 * /move_base:
   * /move_base/cancel


Found 18 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/master_sync_turtlebot2_laptop_12566_8631238841196826973] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/turtlebot_laptop_battery] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/openni_manager] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/robot_state_publisher] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/pointcloud_throttle] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/turtlebot_teleop_keyboard] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/rviz_1337161845242440654] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/rosout] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/move_base] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/turtlebot_node] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/app_manager] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/slam_gmapping] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/kinect_laser] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/openni_camera] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/diagnostic_aggregator] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/robot_pose_ekf] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/rviz_1337161842349946625] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/kinect_laser_narrow] raised an error:
```

This is what my ROSWTF command returns. This is all of a sudden. We were working with the turtlebot all these days. We were experimenting with lots of new programs that we wrote. Yesterday, the turtlebot did not take goals/initial pose given it from rviz. We didn't understand why and we were confused. We saw similar errors on the internet but none helped us. We use electric.

Also, one of our programs that takes messages from a topic did not respond even after the message was successfully posted to the topic. We checked that by using rostopic echo. For the previous case, we checked that the initial pose and the goals were also reaching the topics, using the same rostopic echo. For both cases, we also checked that the nodes are listening and posting on the related topics.

Please see if you can help. I will provide other details, if necessary.

Note: TurtleBot Tele-operation works very fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34120/roswtf-errors,-all-of-a-sudden-!!!/) by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2012-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The temporary solution is to reinstall the ubuntu installation. I did that. Now everything seems to work so fine.

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2012-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) on 2012-05-18**:
I have similar errors with Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04. Did you reinstall Ubuntu or ROS?

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2012-05-20**:
I reinstalled ubuntu. Just reinstalling ROS did not work. I suggest you get back to 11.10. 12.04 is not supported by electric and fuerte is not yet full-fledged!